# Group by in select clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to have group by function as shown below .

```
select 
    sum(c1)
    ,sum(c2)
    ,c3
    ,c4
    ,c5
    ,c6
    ,c7
    ,c8
    ,sum(c9) over (partition by c4,c5,c6) 
from 
    table 1 
group by 
    c3
    ,c4
    ,c5
    ,c6
    ,c7
    ,c8;
```

c9 is summed grouping only c4,c5,c6,but c1 and c2 must be summed group other columns as shown above

is it possible .but i am getting Not a group by expression .please help me .

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want aggregation with window functions:

```
select sum(c1), sum(c2), c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8,
       sum(sum(c9)) over (partition by c4, c5, c6)
from table1
group by c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the ORDER by function..

SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE condition
GROUP BY column_name(s)
ORDER BY column_name(s);